# Arrayoutofbounds before destroying Unity3D GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Expected this object to destroy itself once it exceeds the Array's amount, however, it throws an ArrayOutOfBounds. I was wondering if there would be a solution to this problem.

I also tried:

```
if (ObjectSprite[spriteNumber + 1] == null)
```

I expected that would work but I'm new to developing so I'm stuck here

```
public class DestroyableObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject coin;
    public int spriteNumber = 0;
    public Sprite[] ObjectSprite;

    void Update () 
    {
        SpriteUpdate();
    }

    void SpriteUpdate()
    {
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = ObjectSprite[spriteNumber];

        if (spriteNumber > ObjectSprite.Length)
        {
            Instantiate(coin, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and include the actual error message you're getting.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't start your variable names with capitals. Only class names (aka: types) should be named that way. Variables should always start with a lowercase letter so they don't accidentally conflict with class names. `public Sprite[] objectSprite;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access the array before checking if the `spriteNumber` is greater than the array. You should first check if the `spriteNumber` is out of bounds, then attempt to access the `ObjectSprite`.

```
void SpriteUpdate()
{
    // if we're within the bounds of the array
    if (spriteNumber < ObjectSprite.Length)
    {
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = ObjectSprite[spriteNumber];
    }
    // if we're outside the bounds of the array
    else
    {
        Instantiate(coin, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Note that the condition inside the if statement has been flipped; It will only execute the code inside the if block when the `spriteNumber` is *less* than the array length. An `else` clause is also provided which will instantiate the coin and destroy the object when that previous condition is no longer true (it's out of bounds of the array).

Comment: it still doesn't make sense ... if `spriteNumber > ObjectSprite.Length` you should **not** continue ... you probably ment `if (spriteNumber < ObjectSprite.Length)`

Comment: If `spriteNumber` is the index of the array `ObjectSprite`, shouldn't it be less than the length of the array? Otherwise it will always be out of bounds

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the condition and provided an explanation.